# Merge 2 instances of same class based on ID using Linq/c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an application which gets 2 instances of the same class from different method.I want to merge the 2 instance into 1 instance of the class. Below is the format of the instances

Instance 1

```
[{
"locationId": "ABCD",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Mango",
     }  
}
},
{
"locationId": "EFGH",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Pear",
    }   
}
}]
```

Instance 2

```
[{
"locationId": "ABCD",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Apple",
     }  
}
},

{
"locationId": "EFGH",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Kiwi",
    }   
}
}]
```

I want to merge them so that they appear as below,

```
[{
"locationId": "ABCD",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Mango",
    },
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Apple",
     }  
}
},
{
"locationId": "EFGH",
"Fruits": 
{
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Pear",
    },
 Fruit:
    {
     TypeId: "Kiwi",
    }   
}
}]
```

Is it possible using linq? Could anyone please direct me to the correct path?

Comment: What did you try already? This question is pretty broad.

Comment: Your sample data is strange. It looks like Json but it can't work without some `[ ]` .

Comment: Ok, now it is at least somewhat valid. But the structure of the incoming data suggests it should be an array too. ( `{Fruits: { Fruit }}` ).  And what to do with duplicates?

Comment: You should provide your C# classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join the two lists on `locationId` and than concat the fruits.

```
    var list1 = new[] 
    { 
        new LocationFruit { locationId = "ABCD", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Mango"} }},  
        new LocationFruit { locationId = "EFGH", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Pear"} }}
    };
    var list2 = new[]
    {
        new LocationFruit { locationId = "ABCD", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Apple"} }},
        new LocationFruit { locationId = "EFGH", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Kiwi"} }}
    };

    var result = from a in list1
                 join b in list2 on a.locationId equals b.locationId
                 select new LocationFruit
                 {
                    locationId = a.locationId,
                    Fruits = a.Fruits.Concat(b.Fruits).ToList()
                 };
```

Assumed your classes looked like this:

```
public class LocationFruit
{
    public string locationId { get; set; }  
    public List<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string TypeId { get; set; }  
}
```

Or if you want non matched items from both lists:

```
    var result = list1
                .Concat(list2)
                .GroupBy(
                    x => x.locationId, 
                    (key, items) => new LocationFruit 
                    {
                        locationId = key, 
                        Fruits = items.SelectMany(y => y.Fruits).ToList()
                    });
```

Comment: This kind of works, so how will I do a left join if list1 has only 1 item(with locationid="ABCD" and list 2 has 2 items( with ABCD and EFGH). I wast the final result to have both ABCD and EFGH. I tried  
var result = from a in list1
                 join b in list2 on a.locationId equals b.locationId into a
  from r in a.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 select new LocationFruit
                 {
                    locationId = b.locationId,
                    Fruits = r.Fruits.Concat(b.Fruits).ToList()
                 };
But this does not work for me.

Comment: You want non matched locations from both lists?

Comment: @Magnum,var list1= new[]{ new LocationFruit {locationId= "ABCD", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Mango"} }} }; var list2 = new[] { new LocationFruit { locationId = "ABCD",Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Apple"} }},new LocationFruit { locationId = "EFGH", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Kiwi"} }}  };var result= new []{ new LocationFruit { locationId = "ABCD", Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId = "Mango"},new Fruit { TypeId = "Apple"} }},new LocationFruit {locationId ="EFGH",Fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { TypeId ="Kiwi"} }} };

Comment: something likethe above

Answer (score 1):

So you have two sequence of objects, where every object has a `LocationId` and a `Fruit` (or an array of `Fruits`).

You want a LINQ statement, that results in a sequence of objects where every object has a `LocationId`, and a sequence of all `Fruits` on that location.

For this we use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__)

You forgot to tell us what type of input is. Let's name it:

```
class Fruit {...}

class FruitOnLocation
{
     public string LocationId {get; set;}
     public Fruit Fruit {get; set;}
}
```

It might be that you have a sequence of Fruits on this location. The code will be very similar.

```
IEnumerable<FruitOnLocation> instance1 = ...
IEnumerable<FruitOnLocation> instance2 = ...

var result = instance1.Concat(instance2)       // concatenate the two sequences
    .GroupBy(item => item.LocationId,          // make groups of objects with same LocationId
         (locationId, fruitsOnLocation) => new // from every locationId and all fruitsOnLocation
         {                                     // with this locationId make one new
              LocationId = locationId,         // object containing the common locationId
              Fruits = fruitsOnLocation        // and the list of all Fruits with this
                       .ToList(),              // locationId
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might want to have/use classes as follows:

```
class StockEntry
{
  public IEnumerable<PerLocationStock> Stocks { get; set; }
}

class PerLocationStock
{
  public string LocationId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
}

public class Fruit
{
  public string TypeId { get; }

  public Fruit(string typeId)
  {
      TypeId = typeId;
  }

  protected bool Equals(Fruit other) => string.Equals(TypeId, other.TypeId);

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
     if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
     if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
     return Equals((Fruit) obj);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() => (TypeId != null ? TypeId.GetHashCode() : 0);
}
```

Where your object initialistion would look as follows:

```
var instance1 = new StockEntry
{
  Stocks = new[] {
    new PerLocationStock
    {
      LocationId = "ABCD",
      Fruits = new [] { new Fruit("Mango") }
    },
    new PerLocationStock
    {
      LocationId = "EFGH",
      Fruits = new [] { new Fruit("Pear") }
    }
  }
};

var instance2 = new StockEntry
{
  Stocks = new[] {
    new PerLocationStock
    {
      LocationId = "ABCD",
      Fruits = new [] { new Fruit("Apple") }
    },
    new PerLocationStock
    {
      LocationId = "EFGH",
      Fruits = new [] { new Fruit("Kiwi"), new Fruit("Pear") }
    }
  }
};
```

And finally your merging objects algorithms would look as follows:

```
 var mergedInstance = new[] { instance1, instance2 }
      .SelectMany(se => se.Stocks)
      .GroupBy(pls => pls.LocationId)
      .Aggregate(
        new StockEntry { Stocks = Enumerable.Empty<PerLocationStock>() },
        (stockEntry, groupedByLocationFruits) =>
        {
          var perLocationStock = new PerLocationStock
          {
            LocationId = groupedByLocationFruits.Key,
            Fruits = groupedByLocationFruits.SelectMany(x => x.Fruits).Distinct()
          };

          stockEntry.Stocks = new List<PerLocationStock>(stockEntry.Stocks) { perLocationStock };

          return stockEntry;
        });
```

Next loop over the result in a following way:

```
foreach (var locationStock in mergedInstance.Stocks)
{
      Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(PerLocationStock.LocationId)}={locationStock.LocationId}");
      foreach (var fruitsInLocation in locationStock.Fruits)
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Fruit.TypeId)}={fruitsInLocation.TypeId}");
}
```

And finally get your expected result:

```
LocationId=ABCD
TypeId=Mango
TypeId=Apple
LocationId=EFGH
TypeId=Pear
TypeId=Kiwi
```

Please note that duplicates were removed from the fruits thanks to the `Fruit.Equals`.